# How to manage a C++ project with Subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, subclipse

I am developing a C++ app for Linux using Wind River Workbench 4, which uses Eclipse 4.5.2. I have installed Subclipse 1.12.

We maintain our projects in Subversion but previously haven't used Subclipse. Our workflow has been:

1. Create a new Workbench (CDT) project "in an external location" in
   my svn workspace in C:\SVNProj\ (I'm working on Windows).
2. Save it
3. Import the project into my Eclipse workspace
   (C:\WindRiver\workspace)
4. Add source files to the project as links to the files under C:\SVNProj\.

This worked fine, although remembering to use links was a bit of a pain.

Now I am wondering if the workflow would be easier using Subclipse. I guess that links are then no longer necessary, but I don't understand how that workflow works.

Do I end up with an svn workspace within the Eclipse workspace?

How would I import the existing project that I can see under C:\SVNProj\?

Do I just import the project directory or all of 'trunk'?

best regards

David

Comment: I don't use subclipse anymore so can't pull out screenshots/etc (I only use git with git-svn bridge when I need to connect to SVN projects). However I have provided a part of an answer that may help.

Comment: Hi Jonah, thanks for your reply. I can do what you suggest but I think that just reproduces the way I am working currently. If I work with Subclipse is the svn working copy consequently checked out into the Eclipse workspace?

Comment: Hi DavidA, I don't think it is what you are doing. There should be nothing in your eclipse workspace on disk. i.e. you don't create links within projects but just have Eclipse look for projects in the other folder. The key thing is that you import projects into the workspace without copying them. If you have any file copied (e.g. .project file) then it is going wrong.

Comment: To clarify, your workspace is c:\workspace when you open Eclipse you will have a project called MyProject, the location on disk of MyProject should be C:\SVNProjects\MyProject. Specifically the magic .project file should be C:\SVNProjects\MyProject\.project.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing your project, but without copying into your workspace. Doing that will mean you edit in your SVN directory directly, presumably as you expect.

[image]